Datatable is not populating in Laravel
My JavaScript code is like below.
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#time').change(function() {
        var time = $(this).val(); 
        var url = '{{ route("owner.safety.timeOverview", ":time") }}';
        url = url.replace(':time', time);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: url,
            success: function(data) {

                console.log(data); // I am getting values here

                $('#overview').DataTable({
                    destroy: true, 
                    data: data, 
                    lengthMenu: [10, 25, 50, 75, 100],
                    mimeType: 'json',
                    columns: [
                        { "data": "property_id", "title": "property_id" },
                        { "data": "unit_id", "title": "unit_id" },
                        { "data": "issue_date", "title": "issue_date" },
                        { "data": "expiry_date", "title": "expiry_date" },
                        { "data": "certified_by", "title": "certified_by" },
                        { "data": "safety", "title": "safety" },
                        { "data": "reminder", "title": "reminder" }
                    ],
                    searchPane: {
                        threshold: 0
                    },
                    drawCallback: function() {
                        $(".dataTables_length select").addClass("form-select form-select-sm");
                    },
                    language: {
                        paginate: {
                            previous: '<span class="iconify" data-icon="icons8:angle-left"></span>',
                            next: '<span class="iconify" data-icon="icons8:angle-right"></span>'
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});

My PHP code is like below.
public function getAllTime($time)
{
    if ($time == 'oneweek') {
        $difference = Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()->addWeek();
    }
    if ($time == 'onemonth') {
        $difference = Carbon::now()->addMonth()->endOfMonth();
    }
    if ($time == 'threemonth') {
        $difference = Carbon::now()->addMonths(3)->endOfMonth();
    }
    if ($time == 'sixmonth') {
        $difference = Carbon::now()->addMonths(6)->endOfMonth();
    }

    $propertyIds = Property::where('owner_user_id', auth()->id())->pluck('id')->toArray();

    $data = Safety::with(['property', 'propertyUnit'])
        ->whereIn('property_id', $propertyIds)
        ->whereBetween('expiry_date', [Carbon::now(), $difference])
        ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
        ->get();

    return $data;
}


public function getAllDataTime($time)
{
    $overviews = $this->getAllTime($time);

    return datatables($overviews)
        ->addIndexColumn()
        ->addColumn('property_id', function ($overview) {
            return  $overview->property ? $overview->property->name : '';
        })
        ->addColumn('unit_id', function ($overview) {
            return  $overview->propertyUnit ? $overview->propertyUnit->unit_name : '';
        })
        ->addColumn('issue_date', function ($overview) {
            return  date("d-m-Y", strtotime($overview->issue_date));
        })
        ->addColumn('expiry_date', function ($overview) {
            return  date("d-m-Y", strtotime($overview->expiry_date));
        })
        ->addColumn('certified_by', function ($overview) {
            return  $overview->certified_by;
        })
        ->addColumn('safety', function ($overview) {
            return  ucfirst($overview->type);
        })
        ->addColumn('reminder', function ($overview) {
            if ($overview->expired == 1) {
                return '<div>Expired</div>';
            } else {
                $expiryDate = Carbon::parse($overview->expiry_date);
                $today = Carbon::now();
                $differenceInDays = $today->diffInDays($expiryDate);

                if ($expiryDate->isPast()) {
                    return '<div class = "over_due">Over Due</div>';
                } else {
                    $differenceInDays = $today->diffInDays($expiryDate);
                    if ($differenceInDays < 30) {
                        return '<div class = "due_soon">Due Soon</div>';
                    } else {
                        return '<div class = "not_due">Not Due</div>';
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        ->rawColumns(['reminder'])
        ->make(true);
}

I am getting values when I use console.log(). But my DataTable is empty like below.


Is this a JS problem or a Laravel problem? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

If you are getting data from console.log then you dont need the PHP code to be displayed here. You are executing Datatable in element with id overview Are you sure that overview exists in your code?

Thanks @NicoHaase. Actually I couldn't find out where is the issue. I don't know it is JS problem or Laravel problem. I console.log() the result.

Thanks @Mr.Kenneth. Yes, I am sure that overview exists in my code

Check what Laravel returns - is this the expected result? In the proper structure? Then you're most probably not having a problem with Laravel.

Thanks @NicoHaase. May be I have no problem with Laravel. Actually I don't know where is the issue. I need solution.

"Maybe" sounds like you haven't checked this yet - why not do that, to check which next step you should take?

I don't know Datatables but a quick glance at the docs, possible issue is you are not using the correct Datatable API. 2nd, you have extra key (data) in the column object. 3rd the data structure. As you can see in my code below, data is a multidimensional array (Just a guess since you did not post your data).


const data = [
    ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1', 'e1', 'f1', 'g1'],
    ['a2', 'b2', 'c2', 'd2', 'e2', 'f2', 'g2'],
    ['a3', 'b3', 'c3', 'd3', 'e3', 'f3', 'g3'],
    ['a4', 'b4', 'c4', 'd4', 'e4', 'f4', 'g4'],
    ['a5', 'b5', 'c5', 'd5', 'e5', 'f5', 'g5'],
    ['a6', 'b6', 'c6', 'd6', 'e6', 'f6', 'g6'],
];
new DataTable('#overview', {
    columns: [
        { "title": "property_id" },
        { "title": "unit_id" },
        { "title": "issue_date" },
        { "title": "expiry_date" },
        { "title": "certified_by" },
        { "title": "safety" },
        { "title": "reminder" }
    ],
    data: data, 
});
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.7/css/dataTables.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/2.0.7/js/dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="overview">
</table>



Not sure how Datatables handle null items but for arguments sake, make sure that each row of array has 7 elements.
source: Datatables api
